# Something is wrong with Linux 64-bit 4.0.7 build

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I downloaded and installed `tor-browser-linux64-4.0.7_en-US.tar.xz`. It starts up ok. The browser says it has version 4.0.6, not 4.0.7. Update prompt window pops up after a few minutes.

Something is built wrong with this release.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in TBB. The developers put out a security update of Tor which TBB developers built into Tor. This issue is discussed in [bug entry #15637](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15637). This issue is now fixed. If you download version 4.0.8 or later it should not happen.